# Read CSV file in C# and store in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csv, datatable

I am using following code to read `csv` file and store in to C#. But my requirement is that, I want to skip the first line in `csv` file, since it is not structured, hence take the second row as column. How to do it in the exiting code.

```
private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
{    
   DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

    try
    {

    using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }

            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                 }
                     csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
             }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
   return csvData;
}
```

My CSV file looks like

```
a;;{b;g;t{}
firstname;lastname;age;locaion
peter;vela;28;denver
sasi;kiran;38;colorado
sastri;miro;texas
```

Comment: Tried my answer with your sample data and it works. Note however that you use as field separator the comma, while the file has a semicolon between fields

Answer (score 1):

The [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128082(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a constructor that can receive a stream.
So the idea is: Open a StreamReader on your file, read the first line and discard it, then build the TextFieldParser with the opened StreamReader positioned on the second line where your column names exist.

I have tested it and it seems to work

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csv_file_path))
{
    // Discard the first line... (add checking here)
    reader.ReadLine();
    using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(reader))
    {
       csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { ";" });
       .....
```

I have also set the delimiter to a semicolon instead of a comma according to your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int rowsToSkip = 1;
int position = 0;
while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
    if(position >= rowsToSkip)
    {

        //Making empty value as null
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fieldData[i] == "")
            {
                fieldData[i] = null;
            }
        }
        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
    }
    position++;
}
```

Comment: what about columns?,Here file second row is column rather than first row

Comment: Not sure I understand. You need to skip the first row and read the headers from the second? I think it would be easier if you could post the first three lines of your file.

Comment: You could just check if position == 1, which is where your headers are, and populate data set columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life easy and ready to spend some money. Flexcel will make your life easy.

This thing will be done in 2 lines of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(this.INPUTTFILE);
string[] Fields;
for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    DataRow Row = Dt_Input_With_ColoumName.NewRow();
    Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
    for (int f = 0; f < Dt_Input_With_ColoumName.Columns.Count; f++)
    {
        Row[f] = Fields[f];
    }
    Dt_Input_With_ColoumName.Rows.Add(Row);
}
```